# Convert month name to number in multiple languages in vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, translate

I have strings in multiple languages like this:

```
John's birthday is on May 28, 2020
Johns Geburtstag ist am 28. Mai 2020
El cumpleaños de John es el 28 de mayo de 2020
John ma urodziny w dniu 28 maja 2020 r
```

I need to extract the date from the string in vanilla javascript.
I will know the language of the string, so I'll remove any redundant text through a split/splice - for example on the first and second string, I use the following code to reduce the string to its core date in the local language:

```
string.split(' ').slice(4).join(' ')
```

In the first case, this will return May 28, 2020, in the second case 28. Mai 2020

I've stored the slice # in an object 'langslice', so langslice['de'] == 4; langslice['es'] == 6 etc. So in reality I would use the following for Spanish:

```
string.split(' ').slice(langslice[XX]).join(' ')
```

Where the XX variable holds the language identifier (es) in this case. The above then returns '28 de mayo de 2020'.

Having this string, I want to use vanilla ES3/5 to translate the string to English, so I can ultimately use Date.parse to convert it into a unix timestamp.

```
Date.parse('May 28, 2020')
```

will gladly return 1590616800000, but Date.parse('28. Mai 2020') obviously returns -1.#IND

I was hoping there is a built in way to translate this (without external libraries), so I won't have to make 10+ dictionaries with the month strings in source language and English.

Any hints would be welcome!

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: thanks for your quick reply mplungjan - to be honest, I think my question is quite clear - "is there a way to derive the month number from month names in multiple languages in Javascript" - this does not require example code. The example strings are there. I have definitely looked at related topics, but they all require external libraries and as I stated (even in the question topic), I am looking for a solution in vanilla javascript. I would appreciate it if you take a bit more time to read the request instead of insta-replying that it's wrongly stated.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat

Comment: @JaromandaX for a second I jumped in joy and smacked my head for not using that. Then I remember it doesn't work in ES5

Comment: @mplungjan saw your note/edit - I deleted it as it got closed and wouldn't accept answers, which made it redundant to keep open. I've edited the question a bit, but likely will just use a bunch of month translation dictionaries, as I'll only have to do it once anyway,

Comment: See if my answer helps at all.  It by conjugated month names but perhaps still useful

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this without external libraries unless you hardcode the months for all coutries yourself

This ALMOST works, except the polish may conjugate the month names and the Spanish has de mayo de instead of just mayo

You COULD use startsWith and get a long way

```js
const DateTime = luxon.DateTime;
const f = {month: 'long'};

// you need to get rid of the de mayo de
// you need to get rid of the "r"
let strings = `May 28, 2020
28. Mai 2020
28 mayo 2020 
28 maj 2020` 
.split("\n")

const months = {};
["en","de","es","pl"].forEach(lng => {
  dt = DateTime.local();
  months[lng] = []
  for (let i = 0;i<12;i++) {
    const month = dt.setLocale(lng).set({month:i}).toLocaleString(f)
    months[lng].push(month);
  }
});
console.log(months)

strings = strings.map(str => {
  const monthName = str.match(/[^\d., ]+/)[0];
  Object.values(months).forEach(val => { 
    let monthNum = val.indexOf(monthName);
    if (monthNum > -1) str = str.replace(monthName,monthNum)
  })
  console.log(str)
  return str;
})
console.log(strings);
// this would be faster, but I do not know how to run Info on a web page
// Info.months("long", { locale: "fr" }) //=> [ 'janvier', 'février', ...
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/luxon/1.24.1/luxon.min.js"></script>
```